# Launch intent to specifically add Google account

Tags: android

I am trying to start an activity specifically for adding a Google/Gmail account.
I managed to figure out how to do it for API 18+ using the following.

```
         Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_ADD_ACCOUNT);
         intent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_ACCOUNT_TYPES, new String[]{
                "com.google"
         });

         activity.startActivity(intent);
```

Prior to API 18, the only extra to filter accounts I found was:

```
Settings.EXTRA_AUTHORITIES
```

However, I can't find any documentation on the types of authorities  to use that.  What is the way to specifically launch an intent to add a Google account for earlier APIs?